# Joda-time from LocalDateTime string to LocalDate

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I'm using JodaTime to get the date and time of creation of an account. The format being

```
2017-04-05T12:38:35.585
```

When I get this I store it in my database as a string so I've looked around for ways to format this from a string to LocalDate but haven't been succesful in anything I've found online. My next step is a horrible solution in my opinion to loop through the string until I find the T and remove everything after it. So I'm left with

```
2017-04-05.
```

But Ideally if possible have the date as

```
05/04/2017
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `ISODateTimeFormat` to get a `LocalDateTime` and from this get the `LocalDate`.
Be careful to use the right `Locale`

```
String input="2017-04-05T12:38:35.585";

LocalDateTime ldt = ISODateTimeFormat.localDateOptionalTimeParser()
                    .withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)
                    .parseLocalDateTime(input);

System.out.println(ldt.toLocalDate());//prints 2017-04-05
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using **joda-time 2.7**.

`LocalDateTime` class has a constructor that takes a `String` and parses it. Then you just call `toString()` method with the pattern you want:

```
String input = "2017-04-05T12:38:35.585";
LocalDateTime d = new LocalDateTime(input);
System.out.println(d.toString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Output:

```
05/04/2017
```

**Note**: you can also use `ISODateTimeFormat` to parse and a `DateTimeFormatter` instead of `toString()` to get the output:

```
LocalDateTime d = ISODateTimeFormat.localDateOptionalTimeParser().parseLocalDateTime(input);
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println(fmt.print(d));
```

The output will be the same.

Comment: Thanks, I tried both solutions in both answers and both worked :)